# SMS Send in windows mobile

Tags: sms, windows-mobile

I develop for windows mobile 5.0 for send and receive SMS. first I send the SMS is fine worked. After I received the SMS using MessageInterceptor, after receiving SMS I am not able to send SMS, SMS sending error.

IN Form load

```
MsgInterpret.MessageReceived += new MessageInterceptorEventHandler(MsgInterpret_MessageReceived);
void MsgInterpret_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageInterceptorEventArgs e)
{
 try
 {
    ReceiveMsg = (SmsMessage)e.Message;
    sndrNo = ReceiveMsg.From.Name;
    Msgbody = ReceiveMsg.Body;
    label2.Text = sndrNo;
    textBox1.Text = Msgbody;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
}

private void Send_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            try
            {
                string mAtmId = "Hello Raja"
                SmsMessage sms = new SmsMessage();
                sms.Body = mAtmId;
                sms.To.Add(new Recipient(Txt_PhoneNo.Text.Trim()));
                sms.Send();
                MessageBox.Show("Message send successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

The problem is, send the sms properly before using the `MsgInterpret.MessageReceived` event to receive the sms, after that to send the sms I got the error.

Comment: You give us a hint first! What exactly is the error?

Comment: Hint: Try adding the source code here.